Simple way to track bird after release?
I am raising an abandoned baby bird (either Grackle or Robin) that was found on property.
When it's eventually released, it would be nice to be able to confirm when I see it again in my yard.
From what I can tell, in my country (Canada) it's illegal to put leg bands on birds without getting a license. What are some alternative simple and inexpensive ways to identify the bird?

If lightweight leg bands are forbidden, odds are anything else is too. Check with your local birding or wildlife authorities.
